# Doctrine does not reflect changes after new record is saved

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository

doctrine 2.5 with symfony 3.3

I have a simple application event and participant.

```
function getEventDetail(){
    return eventDetail;
}

function joinEvent(participant) {
    ***First of all***, call getEventDetail() to get latest event detail

    ***if participant is in list (status = 0), update it to be status = 1***
    1. perform update
    2. call getEventDetail()
    3. return eventDetail content 

    ***if participant is not in list, it is a new insert***
    1. perform insert
    2. call getEventDetail()
    3. return eventDetail content 
}
```

My situation is if it's **an update**, the returned eventDetail can reflect the changes. But if it's **an insert**, the returned eventDetail can't reflect the changes. This cause issue the first time user join the event and the returned response doesn't have that information.

More details:
Inside function getEventDetail(), there is something like

```
$queryBuilder = $this->eventRepository->createQueryBuilder('e')
->addSelect('participants_object, customer_object')
->leftJoin('e.participants', 'participants_object')
->leftJoin('participants_object.me','customer_object')
->where('e.event_key = :eventKey')->setParameter('eventKey', $eventKey);

$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
$eventDetailObject = $query->getOneOrNullResult();

$participantCollection = $eventDetailObject->getParticipants();
```

Inside function joinEvent(), mainly it's like following (**if update**)

```
$participant = $this->participantRepository->
findOneBy(['event' => $currentEventDetail['id'], 'me' => $userID]);
$participant->setStatus(1);
$participant = $this->participantRepository->save($participant);
//after update successfully
return $latestEventDetail = $this->getEventDetailByEventKey($eventKey);
```

(**if insert**)

```
$event = $this->eventRepository->getById($currentEventDetail['id']);
$me = $this->customerRepository->getById($userID);
$newParticipant = new Participant();
$newParticipant->setEvent($event);
$newParticipant->setMe($me);
$newParticipant = $this->participantRepository->save($newParticipant);
//if insert success
return $latestEventDetail = $this->getEventDetailByEventKey($eventKey);
```

there is one thing I'd like to point out because I'm not sure if I use the **findOneBy** correctly. **event** and **me** are foreign object linked with **participant** object. (but from the testing result, it's working as expected)

```
$participant = $this->participantRepository->
findOneBy(['event' => $currentEventDetail['id'], 'me' => $userID]);
```

What potential problem cause that difference between update and insert action? thanks.

Comment: Hurry up and add your code to the question. Without it, you will only get downvotes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it's possible to paste all my code here consider that it's too long. But the logic is same as I posted. anyway, let me give out more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last I solve this issue by execute another save query on **event** object

```
$event->addParticipant($newParcipant);
$this->eventRepository->save($event);
```

I think it's something about the cascade issue. But it still doesn't make too much sense for me right now. One of my assumption is doctrine is smart enough that it knows the same query is executed before in the HTTP request, so it returns the same (as stale) data without actually query the database a second time.